# Java Thread Pool ExecutorService: Threads execution order

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

As we create a Thread pool using Java's Executor service and submit threads to this thread pool, what is the order in which those threads get executed?

I want to ensure that threads submitted first, execute first.
For example, in the code below, I want first 5 threads to get executed first, followed by the next 5 threads and so on...

```
// Create a thread pool of 5 threads.
ScheduledExecutorService exService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5, new ModifiedThreadFactory("ReadThreadPool"));

// Create 100 threads.
MyThread[] threads = createMyThreads(100);

// Submit these 100 threads to thread pool for execution.
for(MyThread thread : threads) {
    exService.submit(thread);
}
```

Does Java's Thread Pool provide any API for this purpose, or do we need to implement a FIFO queue at our end to achieve this.
If Java's thread pool does not provide any such functionality, I am really interested to understand the reason behind the non-existence of this functionality as it appears like a very common use-case to me.
Is it technically not possible (which I think is quite unlikely), or is it just a miss?

Comment: buddy it's written in the javadoc of that class

Comment: I hope those `MyThread` objects are just misnamed and do not actually extend `java.lang.Thread`. They should just be `Runnable` tasks. The executor will give them a thread to execute on. (The fact that `Thread` implements `Runnable` is a historical mistake.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default behavior. `ScheduledThreadExecutor` (that you're using although you're not scheduling anything) extends from `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Tasks submitted to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` are stored in a `BlockingQueue` until one thread is available to take them and execute them. And queues are FIFO.

This is decscribed in details in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Tasks are taken out of the queue in FIFO order, but this is not necessarily the order in which they complete if there is more than one worker thread. It's hard to tell if that's what OP is asking though.

Comment: In my test, the task does not start in FIFO order, would you please help to anser my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153013/why-tasks-in-threadpool-are-not-executed-following-fifo-java?noredirect=1#comment71472912_42153013 ?

Answer (score 1):

Threads do not get executed. Threads are the entities running taska like `Runnable` and `Callable` . Submiting such a task to a executor service will put it in it's inner `BlockingQueue` until it gets picked up by a thread from it's thread pool. This will still tell you nothing about the order of execution as different classes can do different things while implementing `Runnable`